# CloudWatch Custom Metric Names Not Showing in Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, grafana-api

I'm new to Grafana and have a query.

I have created a Grafana instance running on EC2 and attached a role with Cloudwatch permisisons to it.

I've configured the Cloudwatch datasource and tested it and it all works fine.

It doesn't look like Grafana is able to load custom metrics by default, so I've specified the names of the custom namespace in the `Namespaces of Custom Metrics field` and I can see them now in the query editor.

However, I don't see any metric names, even though they are present in Cloudwatch.

[image]

But when I select one of the default AWS namespaces, I see all the metric names populated.
[image]

Is there a way to get Metric Names for custom namespaces to show up in Grafana?

Comment: What version of Grafana are you using?

Comment: grafana version 7.2

Comment: Maybe try upgrading it and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: Upgrading worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have correct name in `Namespaces of Custom Metrics field` config. It is case sensitive. Also space there can be a problem. You may try to upgrade your Grafana. It works fine for me with Grafana 8.3.x version.

Comment: Upgrading fixed it. Thanks.